# (C++) error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘int Demo::addTwoNumbers(int, int)’

Tags: c++, boost-python

I'm trying to wrap a simple demo class with a function called "addTwoNumbers" with boost python. Here's the header file:

```
#ifndef DEMO_H_
#define DEMO_H_

#include <boost/function.hpp>

class Demo
{
public:
    Demo() {}
    virtual ~Demo() {}

    typedef void (DemoCb) (int,int,int);
    boost::function<DemoCb> onAddTwoNumbers;

    int addTwoNumbers(int x, int y);

    // Executes a callback within a thread not controlled by the caller.
    void addTwoNumbersAsync(int x, int y, boost::function<DemoCb> callback);

};

#endif /* DEMO_H_ */
```

And here's the wrapping:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include "../demo.h"
using namespace boost::python;

// Create a python module using boost. The name 'demo' must match the name in the makefile
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(python_wrap_demo) {
    // Wrapping the addTwoNumbers function:
    class_<Demo>("Demo", init<>())
        .def("addTwoNumbers", Demo::addTwoNumbers)
    ;
}
```

I got this to work for a similar function, which wasn't wrapped in a class. Why am I now getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `boost::python`, but I believe you just need `&` to pass the address of the member `.def("addTwoNumbers", &Demo::addTwoNumbers)`. Non-member functions and static member functions can be implicitly converted to function pointers, but non-static member functions are different and you need `&` to pass the address.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear; `addTwoNumbers` is a member function of `Demo`, not a static function, yet you are attempting to call it as a static function.  You must have an instance of `Demo` to call it upon.

In your case, `addTwoNumbers` does not need to be a member function, so simply make it static.  For future reference see: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html